# Angular 12 Routing doesn't work when lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular12

I am having a very weird issue with routing and lazy loaded modules.  I have read multiple different articles and guides on lazy loading and routing but have not been able to solve this.  In short, I am lazy loading a few modules, however when I try to use the router navigate() method, I can see the address bar update with the correct url, but the page itself doesn't navigate.  If I then refresh the page, with the the updated address bar, I get to the page I was suppose to originally navigate to.  I've confirmed that the lazy loading aspect is working as expected as I see the chunks load when I hit the appropriate route.  I've also verified that if instead of using lazy loading I load the appropriate component up front the routing works without any issues.

app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService,
    LocalStorageService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./login/login.module').then((c) => c.LoginModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'employer',
    canActivate: [UserGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./employer/employer.module').then((c) => c.EmployerModule),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

employer-module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [EmployerComponent, EmployersComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, EmployerRoutingModule],
})
export class EmployerModule {}
```

employer.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EmployersComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'detail/:id',
    component: EmployerComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class EmployerRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: First try with <li><a routerLink="/employer">To employer</a></li> in your app.component.html.    Do you have a second <router-outlet> for the children pages?. Module login works fine?

Comment: Are you using `ionic`?

Comment: I only have one router outlet.

Comment: But I have another application that uses a similar architecture that only has one router outlet as well.

Comment: I am not using ionic

Comment: @JuanBerzosaTejero I tried that as well and get the same result.

Comment: You have a guard in that route ('employer'). Are you sure that you don't have anything in that guard (UserGuard) that not allow you to activate that route? Try to comment                   // canActivate: [UserGuard], and then run it again (better if you start again from the begginging with ng serve, just in case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found my issue that was messing up my routing.  Inside of my shared.module I was calling AppRoutingModule, which was somehow duplicating all routes and breaking everything.  Routing is now working as expected.